# Save chunks of http.request into grifFS node.js

Tags: node.js, gridfs

You can save the data received from a `http.request` post directly into GridFS to minimize memory usage? Can anyone give me an example,
Note: the size of data are 10Mb+, im using Post to send and i can't do this

```
request.addListener('data', function (chunk) {
    data += chunk;
});
```

because I need to minimize memory usage.
I need something like:

```
request.addListener('data', function (chunk) {
   db.append(chunk);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to first convert the received data to JSON format and then you can simply do:

```
var jsonStr = <your response data>;
db.posts.insert({ "data": jsonStr});
```